# Change Increment value for Identity - SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to change increment value of IDENTITY column in database and I have below restrictions:

1. Can't drop the column.
2. Having around 20k rows.

Dropping table and recreate table with changed increment value would be the solution. I don't know the syntax.

Can you please suggest the syntax or other best possible solution?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: can you show your code ? , we can correct that.

Comment: @JapzDivino: Actually i tried to copy data to temp table, and drop the original table. Again Created original table, But stuck at how to copy data back again with original value of identity column which i took backup in temp table.

Comment: look up `SET IDENTITY_INSERT`

Comment: Q: Have you tried simply changing the identity column's "increment" in the Sql Mgr GUI: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188665%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?

Comment: @paulsm4: Yeah, i tried on save table, it shows like need to recreate the table.

Comment: @PrakashBhagat , i see.. i think what you need is to `ON and OFF` of `IDENTITY_INSERT` , before the insert , you have to set the insert_identity on, syntax is `SET IDENTITY_INSERT [TableName] ON` , then after the insert statement, you have to set the insert_identy to off, syntax is `SET IDENTITY_INSERT [TableName] OFF`

Comment: @JapzDivino: Thank you very much, you gave me helpful hint. I guess that could be right solution.

Comment: @PrakashBhagat Your welcome , i posted the syntax on the answer box, and i think you need to rephrase your question and put your scenario to avoid confusion on the readers :) regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i understand you correctly base on your response to my comment, you backed up the data of the orig table in temp table, then you deleted the orig table and you want to recreate an orig table.

If that is the case , you need the `IDENTITY_INSERT` to set `ON` and `OFF`, because the identity of the table is unique.

The syntax is:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [TableName] ON -- set to on
-- Put your insert statement here
-- insert the data from backed up temp table to your new table
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [TableName] OFF -- set to off
```

Comment: Correct. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2):

If you can accept recreating table, there is no magic about the recreating table syntax.

```
 CREATE TABLE temp_Table
 (
      -- Identity column with new settings
      -- other columns
 );

 INSERT INTO temp_Table
 SELECT -- Columns except identity column
 FROM old_table;

 DROP TABLE old_Table;

 EXEC sp_rename 'temp_Table', 'old_Table';
```

However, you have to handle foreign key by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Altering identity column after table creation is not possible.

Instead, reset SEED value using the below command.

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT('tablename', RESEED, 15)
```

Comment: Thank you for response. Yeah, altering is not possible in mssql server. So want to know the alternative.